# How can I go about sorting pushout vectors in collision resolution?

Tags: c#, math, vector, physics, game-development

Recently I've been working on my game and so far I've got SAT collision detection-resolution working fine (I can detect two polygons intersecting and figure out the correct vector to push one out of another ('pushout' vectors))

However, I have run into a problem when applying the pushout vectors to other polygons. When a polygon gets into contact with 2 or more polygons, I end up with 2 or more pushout vectors, which need to be applied in the right order to get a realistic result (aka not glitching through the other polygons or getting stuck on corners that aren't there)

Currently, I apply every push vector and each time I apply it I check if the polygon is still intersecting with the others it collided with, if so, I keep applying the rest of the vectors. If not, just stop applying as they are not colliding anymore.

The issue with this is that I need to apply the vectors in a specific order, not just in the other they are in the list. I dont know of a good solution to ordering them.

Here's my code (collider is the object that needs to have the pushout vectors applied to it) (otherColliders is a list of colliders that the collider is intersecting):

```cs
List<Vector2> pushoutVectors = getPushoutVectors(otherColliders);

foreach (Vector2 pushout in pushoutVectors)
{
    collider.Transform.Position += pushout;

    if (!collider.checkForIntersecting(otherColliders))
        break;
}
```

The picture below shows my current issue. Is there a solution to getting vector (-1, 0) before (0, 1)?
[image: picture demonstrating the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to sort based on distance from the centre of each collider. Do not sort from the origin point or similar - sort by the distance between the centre of both colliders in ASCENDING order. This ensures that the pushout vectors are applied properly and no clipping or getting stuck occurs.

*sample code:*

```cs
public struct Hit
{
    public Collider Me;
    public Collider Other;
    public Vector2 Pushout;

    public float getCenteredDistanceFromOtherSquared()
    {
        return Vector2.DistanceSquared(Me.getWorldBounds().Center, Other.getWorldBounds().Center);
    }
}
```

```cs
List<Hit> hits = getHits(otherColliders);

// note: this is a long function name for the sake of being clear.
// it returns the distance between the 'collider' and the 'other' collider in the collision
// its squared simply because we just need to order by size not get the actual size, so its just to prevent use of a performance-costly sqrt function
List<Hit> sortedhits = hits.OrderBy(x => x.getCenteredDistanceFromOtherSquared()).ToList();

foreach (Hit hit in sortedhits)
{
    // apply pushout
    collider.Transform.Position += hit.Pushout;

    // check if we're still colliding with any other colliders
    // if we aren't, stop applying hits
    // if we are, keep applying hits
    // this is to prevent getting stuck on edges and such
    if (!collider.checkForIntersecting(otherColliders))
        break;
}
```